# Which is better for hard drive performance, onboard cache RAM or spindle RPM speed?

Tags: hybrid-storage

My HP dv6000 laptop has WD1600BEVS (SATA-I, 160GB, 8MB Buffer, 150 Mbps) hard-dive. I need to upgrade the hard-drive and I am planning for a SATA-II hybrid hard-drive. I have two options -

1. **Seagate ST1000LM014 SSHD** (1TB, 5400RPM, 64MB Cache,
   6Gb/s, 8GB SSD)
2. **Seagate Momentus XT ST750LX003 SSHD** (750 GB, 7200RPM, 32MB Cache,6Gb/s, 8GB SSD)

The former has has lower RPM but higher packing density. But the latter has more RPM but lower packing density. Theoretically, there shouldn't be much difference between the number of sectors covered by the R/W head per unit of time, and hence the amount of data read/written per unit of time (practically, I am not very sure). The former has more cache and is about $10 costlier than the latter (as on Amazon).

Which hard-drive should I go with in terms of performance?

Answer (score 3):

Interesting trade off.  Which is better, more cache RAM or more spindle RPM?

The 8GB SSD pretty much functions as an "L2 cache" in these units, which is going to mask the slower access speed of the 5400RPM somewhat in the first drive.  It also has more cache RAM.

Unless your disk usage pattern is heavy continuous random file I/O, like running a well-used database, I would choose the ST1000LM014.

Consider also that slower RPM drives consume less power and are less prone to head crashes when moved.

Comment: You are right. My usage pattern is mostly random, considering that I mostly work on application development programs (a dozen of them, most frequently). I would be using sequential read/write only when I transfer movies or songs from laptop HDD to portable HDD and vice-versa, which I don't do very frequently.  And yes, consumption of less power and less chances of head-crash are important as I frequently 'move' laptop, in on condition, from one location to another, with-in house though.